# How can i wait until download will be finished?

Tags: swift, swift2

My idea is easy:
1. I have a ViewController with button
2. After click button i want get data from my site 
3. I want put indicator info about data are downloading
4. After finished show message OK or NOT OK

I have a class CCCLass

class CCClass {

```
let CCClass BaseURL: NSURL?
var seed: String?

init() {
    CCClassBaseURL = NSURL(string: "mysiteblabla")
}

func getData() {
    if let CCClassURL = NSURL(string: "", relativeToURL: CCClassBaseURL ) {
        let networkOperation = NetworkOperation(url: CCClassURL)
        networkOperation.downloadJSONFromURL {
            (let JSONDictionary) in
            print(JSONDictionary?["seed"])
            self.seed = JSONDictionary?["seed"] as? String
        }
    } else {
        print("Cold not construct a valid URL")
    }
}
```

}

On click button  i have

```
let ccClass = CCClass()

ccClass.getData() {  
    (let test) in
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         // go to something on the main thread
         print(ccClass.seed)
    }
}
```

And i have error : Cannot invoke 'getData' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'

And i am not sure should I in function getData create Array and return to main thread ? after data will be download i want use this to next http query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a closure parameter in your method if you want to call it with a trailing closure:

```
func getData( completion:()->() ) {
    if let CCClassURL = NSURL(string: "", relativeToURL: CCClassBaseURL ) {
        let networkOperation = NetworkOperation(url: CCClassURL)
        networkOperation.downloadJSONFromURL {
            (let JSONDictionary) in
            print(JSONDictionary?["seed"])
            self.seed = JSONDictionary?["seed"] as? String
            completion()
        }
    } else {
        print("Cold not construct a valid URL")
        completion()
    }
}
```

A good rule of thumb to follow is that any method that takes some kind of "completion" closure should always call that closure even if the operation fails.  So make sure you call `completion()` in your `else` block where URL construction failed, or if a network error occurred, or if a JSON parsing error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `getData` with a trailing closure, but the definition of `getData` doesn't take a closure parameter (or call it). What you have will work if you change the method to take the closure and use it (probably to pass the download result back).